# removing a character from a string in C++

Tags: c++

I am aware of the fact that there already exist solutions to this that make use of the `#include <algorithm>` but I was wondering if the following could be a viable way of doing it:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void remove_character_from_result(string& result, char remove){
    int size = result.size(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        int pos = result.find(remove); 
        if(pos == result.npos) break;
            else{
                if(pos == 0)
                    result = result.substr(1); 
                else
                    result = result.substr(0, pos) + result.substr(pos + 1);
            }
    }
}
int main() {
    string result = "Asad Ahmad";
    remove_character_from_result(result, 'A');
    cout << result << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have tested my code against normal test cases and it does seem to work, I am not sure whether the time complexity would be any better than `result.erase(remove(result.begin(), result.end(), 'A'), result.end());` would appreciate if any one could shed some light on this :) PS I apologize for not using references instead of pointers or '*' instead of '->' earlier - this is code that I have written that I am not really proud of..

Comment: This is too complicated. `std::remove_if`, followed by `erase()` is: 1. shorter, 2. cleaner, 3. easier to read.

Comment: (assuming this is homework, because it's silly to re-invent the standard library) You do not want to iterate over all positions, AND use find.  Pick one or the other. It would also be easier to build a new string and use it, than to keep modifying the original.

Comment: Why do you keep writing `(*result).` instead of `result->`?

Comment: I second the comments already made, but would suggest that you investigate references instead of pointers, given that way it is used here.  Homework or not, good luck - C++ is a tough one.  By the way, you should read about how strings are generally implemented in C++; often just string values will do quite nicely.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik just `remove` I think. `auto new_end = std::remove(s.begin(), s.end(), char_to_remove);   s.erase(new_end, s.end());`

Comment: If you really need to write optimized versions of STL functions, you should be doing it in C or even Assembly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really insist on doing this on your own, you probably want to use `string`'s member functions to do the searching. For a (probably tiny) gain in efficiency, you also want to do the searching from the end back to the beginning of the string. I'd also pass the string by reference instead of passing a pointer.

Finally, instead of building a new string out of substrings, you might as well just erase the character you want gone:

```
void remove_character(string &result, char remove) {   
    std::string::size_type pos;
    while ((pos = result.rfind(remove)) != std::string::npos)
        result.erase(pos, 1);
}
```

If you want to optimize a little (or *possibly* even quite a bit) more, you can resume the second and subsequent searches from the point where you found the previous instance:

```
void remove_character(string &result, char remove) {   
    std::string::size_type pos = std::string::npos;
    while ((pos = result.rfind(remove, pos)) != std::string::npos)
        result.erase(pos, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code has an assortment of issues.

```
#include <iostream>
```

If you are going to access the `std::string` class, you need to `#include <string>`. You shouldn't rely on it being included by `<iostream>`

```
using namespace std;
```

This is a terrible practice, polluting your global namespace with all the names from `std`. If you want to avoid having to repeat a specific name, prefer the syntax

```
using std::string;
```

for example.

```
void remove_character_from_result(string* result, char remove){
```

Your code doesn't check for this pointer being null. It would be better to take the parameter by reference.

```
void remove_character_from_result(string& result, char remove){

int size = (*result).size();
```

While `(*result).size()` achieves the end, you should probably use `->` to remind yourself you're working with a pointer, and perhaps remember to check it isn't null.

```
size = result->size();
```

Here we run into a bug in your program too:

```
int size = result->size();
```

`size()` returns a `std::string::size_type` which is unsigned and possibly significantly larger that `int`. Your code stops working as soon as a string is larger than `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`.

This should either be

```
auto size = result->size();
```

or

```
std::string::size_type size = result->size();

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
```

Again we have the size problem here, but we also have the problem that the size may change during our operations. You should replace both of these lines with:

```
for (std::string::size_type i = 0; i < result->size(); ++i) {
```

The next chunk of code:

```
    int pos = (*result).find(remove); 
    if(pos == (*result).npos) break;
        else{
            if(pos == 0)
                *result = (*result).substr(1); 
            else
                *result = (*result).substr(0, pos) + (*result).substr(pos + 1);
```

doesn't make a whole lot of sense, and does things the hard way. In the first case, you create a new substring and then copy it into yourself. In the second case you create two temporary substrings which you add together creating a third, and then you copy this into yourself.

It would be better to use `erase`.

It's also not clear why you have the size-constrained loop in the first place.

You could better replace the whole function with something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void remove_character_from_result(std::string& result, char remove) {
   for (size_t pos = 0; (pos = result.find(remove, pos)) != result.npos; ) {
       size_t end = pos + 1;
       while (end < result.size() && result[end] == remove)
           ++end;
       result.erase(pos, end - pos);
   }
}

int main() {
    std::string s = "hello world";
    remove_character_from_result(s, 'l');
    std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

The time complexity of this for worst case is that it has to remove half the characters, which would be O(NlogN).

You could improve the performance by working from the right rather than the left: Consider removing the character 'a' from 'ababab'. The first erase is followed by copying 5 characters left, the second erase 3 characters and the third erase 1 character. If we worked the other way around, the first erase would be 1 character, the second erase 2 and the third erase 3.

Comment: This looks like `O(n^2)` to me. Each `erase` call has to shift the rest of the string over which is an `O(n)` operation, and if every character gets removed, you're doing `n` shifts. Am I misreading?

Comment: @RyanHaining Each erase would be `O(N-1)`, and with the while loop in the middle, the worst-case scenario is, e.g., `remove("ababab", 'a')`. Because we're removing and skipping one character each time, each subsequent erase is reduced by 2. So, it's O(NlogN), not O(N*N). I edited the complexity section to clarify what I was saying about better perf if you ran the loop from the right instead of the left, though.

Comment: "*each subsequent erase is reduced by 2*" how does that get you `lg(n)`? What if your string was "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab"?

Comment: @RyanHaining then it would erase all the `a`s in one operation, which would copy `b` to position 0 and reduce size to 1. Again, worst case is removing `a` from `abab...ab`. Read the code again and note the inner while loop that makes the `erase` a range erase when `remove` occurs in sequence.

Comment: ah ok so yeah you've optimized the repeated case, but I'm still not seeing how the "abababababababababa" case is handled in O(nlg(n)), since you're not cutting out half of the remaining 'a's at each step. Is each erase not an `O(n)` operation there?

Comment: @RyanHaining No, because the N is the original size of the string. The first erase in taking `a` from `ababab` is (len=6, dst=0, src=1, chars=5) or O(N-1) leaving `babab`, the second erase is (len=5, dst=1, src=2, chars=3) or O(N-3) leaving `bbab`, the final erase is (len=4, dst=2, src=3, chars=1) or O(N-5).

Comment: @kfsone, I have thought a lot about your proposed solution and the time complexity and I think this is as good as it can get; +1, P.S apologies for being lazy and writing bad code , not taking into consideration before the pointers that you mentioned, this was quite useful, cheers :)

Comment: @ksfone those numbers look like O(lg(n)) because the string is so small. if the string is 100 characters long you're moving 99, then 97, then 95, and so on, and that's an O(n) operation

Comment: @ksfone also O(N-c) is O(n)

Comment: @RyanHaining I didn't say O(lgN), its O(NlgN). For it to be N*N the inner loop would need to be near constant, but its not. For a string of 100 alternating chars its 99 the first iteration and 1 the last. Its never N.

Comment: @kfsone I'm saying the *erase* is O(n). Of course it's never actually going to take n time, in the worst case you're looking at N/2 runs of the outer loop, and then each inner erase being N - i for i in [0, s.length()). The sum of all of those inner runs is (N*((N+1)/2)/2) which, without the constants, is N*N.
Or tell me what I'm missing here: if we have a string of length 100 "babab...ba" and we run over this, we have 98, 96, 94, ..., 2 moves. Expressed as sum(range(0, 100, 2)) (python) that's a total of 2540 moves. 100*lg(100) is ~665

Comment: if you have something like 'ababababab.....' of length N and you want to remove the character 'a', then essentially you need to scan half of the characters, the total complexity should be n/2 (2 + (n - 1) 2 ) ~ O(n^2), each inner loop would be O(1) in this case, if you have something like 'aabaabaabaabaabaab..' of length N, then total complexity should be 2 * n/ 2 (3 + (n - 1) 3)  ~ O(n^2), if you have something like 'aaaaaaaaa....b', and you want to remove a this would be a complexity of O(n) and I am assuming this is the best case?

Comment: @kfsone "*99 the first iteration and 1 the last*" with an average of N/2. *edit*: wait, yes correct though OP said O(n^2)?